# OSX (and also iOS): Is there a way to know the cached user GPS locations?

Tags: ios, macos, geolocation, location

To determine the user's location, I use the CoreLocation framework (I am currently working on a OSX app (location determined thanks to wifi) but my question can also potentially apply to an iOS app) and the following delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

When for some reason, the user location cannot be found (for example if the computer of the user is not connected to internet), the following method is called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

In this case, I would like to get the last known user location. I wonders if there is a way to get this last known location. Is there an array of formerly determined locations somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocation

Accoding to that,

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocation *location
```

> The value of this property is nil if no location data has
>   ever been retrieved. **In iOS 4.0 and later, this property may contain a
>   more recent location object at launch time.** Specifically, if
>   significant location updates are running and your application is
>   terminated, this property is updated with the most recent location
>   data when your application is relaunched (and you create a new
>   location manager object). This location data may be more recent than
>   the last location event processed by your application.

So this is the only way to get the last known location.
If it's not nil, you can use it!

Comment: If you are going to use the significant location changes service, no

Comment: i dont care about the changes, i just need to know the estimated location within 5-10 kilometers